# phpversion() and sqlite_libversion() not returning anything

Tags: php, sqlite

I am on a corporate hosting solution, and trying to test for the existence of sqlite. I am running the following code:

```
<?php
echo sqlite_libversion(), "\n", phpversion();
?>
```

But I am getting a blank page. I know PHP is running because `phpinfo()` is successful, however this is not enough to tell me if sqlite is running as the sqlite.ini is present in `phpinfo()` but can't find any other information.

I am accessing the server via FTP and am locked into the web-root. Does anyone know why `phpversion()` and `sqlite_libversion()` are returning nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the SQLite is not available, the `sqlite_libversion()` function will not even exist and will just throw a PHP error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlite_libversion()

You need to use [function_exists()](http://es.php.net/function_exists) to test if the function is actually there.

Additionally, you should configure error reporting so you can actually see error messages. You have several ways to do so:

1. Edit your `php.ini`file:

   ```
   error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
   display_errors = On
   ```
2. Put this on top of your script:

   ```
   <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
   ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
   ```
3. If PHP runs as Apache module, you can also use an `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   # Print E_ALL | E_STRICT from a PHP script to get the appropriate number:
   php_value error_reporting 2147483647
   php_flag display_errors on
   ```

---

**Update:**

What do you get if you run this code and nothing else?

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

var_dump(phpversion());
if( function_exists('sqlite_libversion') ){
    var_dump(sqlite_libversion());
}

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am locked into web-root and option 2 is not showing any errors.

Comment: This is also showing nothing: `echo (function_exists ("sqlite_libversion")) ? "sqlite exists" : "not here";`

Comment: Cheers I get this: `string(15) "5.2.6-1+lenny13"`

Comment: It's not installed, an error on the page was stopping the `function_exists()` from running. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

take out the echo, just do

```
<?php
     phpversion();
     sqlite_libversion();
?>
```

Comment: Both functions do nothing else than returning a string. If you don't use the returned value, the code is meaningless.

Comment: You are right. It didn't even hit me it was phpversion and not phpinfo